# Click and get info in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a separate database supermarkets and their suppliers. I have as well database which suppliers provide products to particular supermarket.
I would like to create such a tool/solution where after clicking on the point on map (which is supermarket) I will receive a message with their suppliers. It could be short message and "flash" of the suppliers.

I am new in gis, does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you please add more information on what you have tried, and what you want the end product to look like? For example, based on your `qgis` tag, do you want this to be contained within QGIS?

Comment: Thank you for response. 
Please check png file which show simple example. Supermarkets 1,2 and 3 are equipped with products provided from group A, B and C.
1,2,3 - supermarkets
A,B,C - suppliers
The idea is to click on point 1 and receive a message with a list of suppliers form group C.

Comment: There is no image.

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup Please check below link which show simple example.
http://imgur.com/nY3Xit4

Comment: Any advices how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I suspect you will need to write your own QGIS plugin, although that does seem overkill. Conceptually, this is just a one-to-many join, but because you want additional display steps, you will need to tell QGIS what those should be: hence, a plugin.

Comment: To resolve your problem i propose: 1) - make a point layer for "Supermarket" with attribute ID_Supermarket. 2) - make a point layer for "Suppliers" with attribute ID_Supermarket and other..., ex. Product_name. 3) - Use Vector>Data Managment tools>Join attributes by location and pick target layer (Supplierse) and a layer to join (Supermarket), and select keep all records...for output table. 4) - Save as new layer.